# Which authors do I use when citing technical documentation which is community-editable and has multiple contributors?

Tags: citations, software, bibtex

Let's take [this sample page from Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/6.0). It lists multiple contributors (linked below the heading), some from the community with nicknames, as the pages can be edited by practically everyone by submitting a pull request.

Previously, I've tried to identify the “main” author (as in, the person who initially created the page), and using “and others” for the remaining contributors, for example:

```
@Online{Doe2021,
  author  = {Doe, John and others},
  url = ...,
  urldate = ...,
  (and so on)
}
```

However, this can be relatively time-consuming and may result in authors, where the real name is not readily identifiable. I wondered if it was enough to use a company author, since the list of authors may already change the next day, and they're not that important to identify a particular web page. This would essentially result in:

```
@Online{Microsoft2021,
  author  = {{Microsoft}},
  url = ...,
  urldate = ...,
  (and so on)
}
```

Or is there an even different way, i.e., should I make the effort to identify and list as many authors as possible?

Comment: Microsoft is just fine,

Comment: I had this issue this week, would love to have a "canonical" answer. I have tried, when there is an anchor in the website, to add a link to it (`author={https://csci-1301.github.io/about.html#authors}`), but it feels weird.